# How to include last updated row in RoR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have two models, `Category` and `Topic` and any category can have many topics.

The question is, how do I query for all categories and include each category's last updated topic?

If I do something like this

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_one :last_updated_topic, -> {order(updated_at: :desc)}, class_name: 'Topic'
end
```

and query like that ->

```
Category.all.includes(:last_updated_topic)
```

then it works, but what scares me, is that I have a SQL query loading the topics like that:

```
SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."category_id" IN (1, 2, 3)  ORDER BY "topics"."updated_at" DESC
```

so it loads all the topics, which there can be thousands, when I need only last updated ones for each category.

So I wonder if there is a simple way to solve this problem without writing custom SQL or if I am wrong about something?

Should I use this instead? ->

```
SELECT categories.*, t.title as last_topic_title FROM "categories" LEFT JOIN (SELECT topics.* FROM topics ORDER BY topics.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) t ON categories.id = t.category_id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Associations has\_one Latest Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824041/rails-associations-has-one-latest-record)

Comment: @jvnill I am not sure it's a complete dublicate but it seems like I am gonna have to use that custom SQL after all, I wonder if it's correct though ...

Comment: @JustMichael Why are you planning to *join* BTW ?

Comment: @JustMichael look at my answer in that question.  What you want to do is a little hard specially if you're going to use that association in other scopes.  It's better to cache the last updated topic id in the category table.

Answer (score -1):

You can use *inner* query :

```
has_one :last_updated_topic, -> { where(updated_at: Topic.maximum(:updated_at)), class_name: 'Topic'
```

Comment: It's maximum instead of max, it's :updated_at instead of just updated_at and it doesn't work correctly anyway

Comment: @JustMichael why didn't work, BTW.. Show me the SQL please

Comment: it didnt work because it uses the updated_at field of the last updated row in all topics, not only the topics that belong to specific category

Comment: @JustMichael Can you show me the SQL query it is printing ?