# Rails activerecord query with has_many belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have two ActiveRecord models: **User** and **Course**. Which are associated as following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now my question is: how can I get the last course of each user?

I tried following:

```
courses = Array.new
User.find_each { |u| courses << u.courses.last }
```

But I'm doubt on its performance. So looking for best solution with good performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need a single SQL query to get the last courses of all the users at once I guess.. am I right @Ganesh

Comment: Yes, I need a single SQL query for this. @illusionist

Comment: You can solve this using joins and stuff with raw SQL but I have not been able to solve it using activerecord methods. I think using `include` and accept the total of 2 sql queries is the best solution since it is way less complicated than the SQL way.

Comment: @Albin can you please give me the hint?

Comment: Well, is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the last course of each User you can do this:

```
courses = []
User.includes(:courses).find_each { |u| courses << u.courses.last }
```

Comment: he says he needs a SQL Query, if its possible

Answer (score 1):

I still think that it might be easier to just accept 2 queries. But I found the article I looked at before deciding to do it in 2 queries. This works but it adds quite a bit of complexity.

[Rails Associations has_one Latest Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824041/rails-associations-has-one-latest-record)

Answer (score 1):

In 2 requests :

```
User.select(:id).includes(:courses).each { |u| u.courses.last }
```

Doesn't work if your tables are too big

Answer (score 1):

An other way with 1 SQL query

```
Course.all.group_by(&:user_id).map { |_k,courses| courses.last }
```

Comment: That's definitely not the expected behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Like that you can find out the last course for a user

```
User.find(1).courses.order(name: :ASC).last
```

If you want to have an array:

```
courses = []

User.each do |u|
   courses << u.courses.order(name: :ASC).last
end
```